# Excel merge using POI jar in java. but merge is not working as expected

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am getting error while run this application. In the `sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress)` line getting error due to the four args are mismatching. Could anyone help me out?

```
import com.boeing.models.BDIPContent;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
public class BDIPExcelGenerateMerge {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    log.info("BDIPExcelGenerateMerge: main() started");
    String[] excelHeader = {"CEF", "Input File", "RDC", "Data Subject", "Main Segment", "Key 
 Field", "Key Field Value", "Reason"};
    String[][] recordsData = {
            {"CEF1", "0520_B777_FMR.pdf (view)", "VBI", "FH", "AID segment", "AIN1", "A23412", 
"In file Duplicate Record"},
            {"CEF1", "0520_B777_FMR.pdf (view)", "VBI", "FH", "AIDI segment", "AIN1", 
 "A23413", "In file Duplicate Record"},
            {"CEF1", "0820_B777_FMR.pdf(view)", "VBI", "FH", "AID segment", "AIN2", "A23414", 
 "Not convertible dates are given in input records\n"},
            {"CEF2", "CR102020_LAN_17.xls(View)", "VBI", "SI", "AIDO segment", "AIN2", 
 "A23416", "Not convertible dates are given in input records\n"},
            {"CEF2", "CR102020_LAN_17.xls(View)", "VBI", "SI", "AID segment", "AIN3", 
 "A23417", "In file Duplicate Record-1"},
            {"CEF2", "2.pdf(view)", "VBI", "SI", "AIDO segment", "AIN4", "A23418", "In file 
  Duplicate Record"},
            {"CEF3", "3.pdf(view)", "LAN", "CR", "AID segment", "AIN4", "A23419", "In file 
  Duplicate Record"},
            {"CEF3", "3.pdf(view)", "LAN", "CR", "AID9 segment", "AIN5", "A234110", "In file 
  Duplicate Record"},
            {"CEF1", "0520_B777_FMR1.pdf (view)", "VBI67", "FH", "AID segment-1", "AIN1", 
  "A23412", "In file Duplicate Record"}
    };
    log.info("invoking generateExcelMerge() method");
    generateExcelMerge(excelHeader, recordsData);
}

public static void generateExcelMerge(String[] excelHeader, String[][] recordsData) {
    log.info("generateExcelMerge: method invoking started.");
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Rejected_Sheet");
    // Create header CellStyle
    Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
    headerFont.setBold(true);
    headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.index);
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((int) 0);
    HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
    style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
    style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());

    log.info("generateExcelMerge: setting column width");
    for (int i = 0; i < excelHeader.length; i++) {
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(excelHeader[i]);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(i, 20 * 200);
    }

    log.info("generateExcelMerge: setting column style");
    for (int i = 0; i < recordsData.length; i++) {
        row = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < recordsData[0].length; j++) {
            HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(j);
            cell.setCellStyle(style);
        }
    }

    int rowNumber = recordsData.length;//Rows
    int columnNumber = recordsData[0].length; // number of columns
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++) {
        index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < rowNumber; j++) {
            BDIPContent bdipContent = new BDIPContent();
            bdipContent.setContent(recordsData[j][i].toString());
            if (j == rowNumber - 1) {
                //System.out.println(((short) index + 1)+" : "+((short) i)+" : "+((short) j + 
      1)+" : "+((short) i));
    //                    if(  (((short) index + 1) ==  ((short) i)) &&   (((short) j + 1) == 
       ((short) 
   i))) {
    //                        break;
    //                    }
                log.info("generateExcelMerge: cell merge start");
                CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress((short) index + 1 , 
         (short) j + 1, (short) i, (short) i);
                sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress);
                sheet.getRow(index + 1).getCell(i).setCellValue(bdipContent.getContent());
            } else {
                bdipContent.setOldContent(recordsData[j + 1][i].toString());
            }

            if (!bdipContent.getContent().equals(bdipContent.getOldContent())) {
 //                    if(  (((short) index + 1) ==  ((short) i)) &&   (((short) j + 1) == 
                ((short) 
    i))) {
 //                        break;
   //                    }
                log.info("generateExcelMerge: cross checking content with oldContent");
                //System.out.println("oldContent:   "+((short) index + 1)+" : "+((short) i)+" 
           : "+((short) j + 1)+" : "+((short) i));
                CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress((short) index + 1  , 
                (short) j + 1 , (short) i, (short) i);
                sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress);
                sheet.getRow(index + 1).getCell(i).setCellValue(bdipContent.getContent());
                if (j == rowNumber - 2) {
                    // the last line of the previous line are not the same
                    sheet.getRow(index + 
   2).getCell(i).setCellValue(bdipContent.getOldContent());
                    break;
                }
                index = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    //Generate a temporary file
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    String fileName = 
    "D:\\BdipExcelMergeRejectedStatus\\src\\resources\\RecordRejectedStatus.xls";
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
        System.out.println(fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("generateExcelMerge: catch() " + e.getStackTrace());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("generateExcelMerge: catch() " + e.getStackTrace());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    log.info("generateExcelMerge: method invoking End.");
}
}
```

---

model as:

```
public class BDIPContent {
 private String content;

 private String oldContent;

 public String getOldContent() {
    return oldContent;
 }

 public void setOldContent(String oldContent) {
    this.oldContent = oldContent;
 }

 public String getContent() {
    return content;
 }

 public void setContent(String content) {
       this.content = content;
 }
 }
```

Getting output:

[image: Screenshot with the error]

---

Help me out to resolve the issue.
Much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: If i comment out sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress) line I am getting out put without cells merge.

Comment: Try to debug. The error occurs because in code line `CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress((short) index + 1 , (short) j + 1, (short) i, (short) i);` variable `index` is 2 and `j` also is 2 and `i` is 1. That leads to a `CellRangeAddress` `B4`. And one cell cannot be a merged region.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out from Monday onwards to correct the logic arguments but I could not able to fix it. Could you please try from ur end for me?